# Why after .switchClass the div is not more selectable?

Tags: html, selector, switch-statement, mouseover

I think that the problem could be easily resolved...but not by me!
I want to create two different animations for my div:hover, the first uses CSS (for the people who won't active javascript in IE) and the second uses JS.
The choice between the two methods is simple, the activation of switchClass function using jqwery. But after this happened the selector for the new class doesn't work and not even the mouseover function!

HELP ME PLEASE!!

Here the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( ".plateMiddle" ).switchClass( "plateMiddle", "plateMiddleFX");
    });

$(".plateMiddleFX").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).stop().find('img').animate({opacity: '0'},{queue:false, duration:500}),
    $(this).stop().animate({width: '265'},{queue:false, duration:500});
    });
```

I don't kwow if could generate problem but inside the div there is an image with more or less the same dimensions.
An other information: if I select directly the image by a class selector the animation takes life!

THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".plateMiddleFX").live('mouseover', function () {
  $(this).stop().find('img').animate({opacity: '0'},{queue:false, duration:500}),
  $(this).stop().animate({width: '265'},{queue:false, duration:500});
});
```